# Don't search text placeholders in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a blog running on MySQL. On the `blog_post` column, I use text placeholders then substitute them on the server side before publishing the blog post.

**Example:**

I have a blog post where I include a link to the contact page. Since all my links must have the base href, I usually write them like this `<a href="{basehref}contact">Contact Page</a>` then substitute the {basehref} placeholder with the actual URL before displaying the blog post.

Another example is including inline blog images; I usually do this `<img src="{assets}images/image.jpg" />` the replace the `assets` placeholder with the actual path.

The question is, if someone searches for `basehref` or `assets` the blog posts containing this placeholder will be selected. How can I tell MySQL to ignore any word between `{` and `}` during searches?

Comment: You don't want to; what is most likely already a very expensive query, assuming you're using something like `...where body like '%keyword%'...` (look up [sargability](https://www.google.com/search?q=sargability)), will become very much more expensive to 'weed this out'.

Comment: Two suggestions. 1). Maintain an `index` column in the database table, which contains the post content stripped of all HTML markup. This will prevent false positives on other tag attribute values too. 2). Use a full-text search library (e.g. Lucene) and parse the content before building the index. This would also allow you to apply different weightings to various fields for more sophisticated results ordering.

Comment: @fubar I like the index proposal. I may consider it if nothing else shows up.

Comment: @Parto the `index` column is a dirty solution, but when you're looking for a quick win it works surprisingly well, especially when combined with a full-text index.

Comment: *The question is, if someone searches for `'basehref'` or `'assets`' the blog posts containing this placeholder will be selected.* `'base'` and `'asset'` too... *How can I tell MySQL to ignore any word between { and } during searches?* Replace all placeholders with empty strings before searching (expensive, index usage lost). Or use searching in CTE/subquery "as is", then refine search in outer query and remove wrong records.